# Vuejs 3.2 Emit from a children for an other children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have 3 components: 1 parent and 2 children in my chess app.

In the first child (Board), I update move and fen (chess notation)

```js
const emit = defineEmits(['fen', 'move'])

function move() {

[...]

    emit('fen', game.fen())
    emit('move', orig, dest)
}
```

And the parent gets fen and move updates.

```js
<template>
<div>
     <board @fen="updatefen" @move="updateMove"></board>
     <explorer :fen="currentFen"></explorer>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

let currentfen = ref('')
function updatefen(fen){
  currentfen.value = fen
}
</script>
```

Now, when fen is updated, I want to update explorer component (the other child)

```js
<template>
<div>fen : {{fen}}</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  fen: {
    type: String
  }
})
watch(() => props.fen, () => {
  console.log('new fen')
})
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Events can only be emitter to the immediate parent or to an event bus. IF you need 2 sibling children to communicate with each other - you will need an event bus.

Comment: Thanks.
After reading your comment, i use Pinia Store and watcher.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you want to handle event between different components. To reach your goal, you need to use third event lib like `mitt`. [example to use mitt](https://medium.com/@certosinolab/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-3-425aae8c21a6)